# JSoup Not Producing Valid XHTML

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSoup to dynamically set the href attribute of a `<base/>` element in an HTML document. This works as expected apart from the fact the closing `</base>` tag is omitted from the modified HTML.

Is there any way to have JSOUP return valid XHTML?

Input:

```
<html><head><base href="xyz"/></head><body></body></html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="https://myhost:8080/myapp/"> <-- missing closing tag
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
  protected String modifyHtml(HttpServletRequest request, String html)
  {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
    Elements baseElements = document.select("base");

    if (!baseElements.isEmpty())
    {
      Element base = baseElements.get(0);
      base.attr("href", getBaseUrl(request));
    }

    return document.html();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to (or instead of) the escape mode, you want to set the syntax:

```
document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using that instead of setting the escape mode fixes.